# How to prevent a trigger from firing so that duplicate data is not entered into a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have 3 tables like this:

`authorGenres (authorGenreId, authorId, isPublished)`

`bookLibrarys (bookLibraryId, authorGenreId, bookId)`

`bookList (bookId, authorId)`

I created a trigger, that fires when a row is updated in `authorGenres` and the `isPublished` column is set to `1`.

When that happens, the trigger INSERTS a row into the `bookLibrarys` table where the `authorGenreId` column is set to the row that was updated in `authorGenres`

Here is my working trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[setCorrectGenreAfterUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[authorGenres]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @bookID AS NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @bookLibraryId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @author IDUNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    SELECT @authorID = Inserted.authorID FROM inserted;

    SET @bookLibraryId = NEWID(); 
    SET @bookID = ( SELECT bookId 
                    FROM booklist nl 
                    WHERE nl.authorID = @authorID)

    INSERT INTO booklibrarys(bookLibraryID, parentBookID, genreID)
    SELECT @bookLibraryId, @bookID, genreID FROM Inserted

END
```

When I do a test UPDATE like this `UPDATE dbo.authorGenres SET isPublished = 1 WHERE genreID = 'C325061D-4274-487B-93F9-03BEB8B7D4D5'`, it works and inserts a new row into `bookLibrarys`.

The problem is, if I do that update again, I get another new row in `bookLibrarys` with the same authorGenreId and bookId, but a new bookLibraryId because that is generated in the trigger.

Is there a way to have the trigger only run if a row with that bookId and authorGenreId doesn't exist in `bookLibrarys`?

Thanks!

Comment: Careful, the trigger you have assumes that an `UPDATE` only affects one row; that simply isn't true.

Comment: @Larnu Im sorry Im totally new to triggers.  Where do I make that error?  I will need to fix that.  thank you

Comment: Have a look at [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: @Larnu thanks I read that site.   Do you think a stored procedure would be better for this type of behavior?  The reason I picked a trigger, is because I can have it run automatically.

Comment: @Larnu thank you with your learning service, that was a good reader site.  Even though it said 2009 I think it is good.  thanks again

Comment: Although I don't agree with all of Bertrand's "bad" habits, they are well worth a read; a lot of them *are* bad and getting out of the "habit" early is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with LEFT JOIN to check if same record already exist, and make sure to have a code that works on multiple rows as @Lamu suggested to you in comments.

Something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[setCorrectGenreAfterUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[authorGenres]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO booklibrarys(bookLibraryID, parentBookID, genreID)
    SELECT NEWID(), bl.bookId, ins.genreID FROM Inserted ins
    INNER JOIN booklist bl ON bl.authorID = ins.authorID -- this is to get  bookId for each row, not for one like in variable
    LEFT JOIN booklibrarys blib ON blib.genreID = ins.genreID AND bl.bookId = 
blib.parentBookID
    WHERE blib.bookLibraryID is NULL
END
```

Comment: You mean work on multiple rows in my `INSERT` at the bottom?

Comment: Yeah, do not store anything in variable, just work with Inserted like with table :) And LEFT join to check for existence to not cause duplicates

Comment: thanks! What about the `@bookID` that I need from bookList?  That gets inserted into the new row in bookLibrarys as well.  thanks again for your learning.

Comment: Yeah, look carefully on what i'm doing, before LEFT JOIN i have an INNER JOIN on booklist to get the bookId

Comment: Oh I see it, sorry.  Does that INSERT statement just insert one row?

Comment: No, that INSERT statement inserts as many rows as updated (and doesn't have duplicate already). If you UPDATE one row - it will insert one row

Comment: I see now, that makes sense.  I didn't know the `LEFT JOIN` would protect me from duplicate rows thank you

Comment: It won't by itself, but with WHERE rightTable.Id IS NULL. That's how it's usually done :)